# Seagate 2T external hard drive can not be mounted, detected by lsusb but not by fdisk -l

Tags: 16.04, mount, external-hdd

I have been having problem with this Seagate 2T external hard drive (type: HPFS/NTFS/exFAT) on my thinkpad VM machine.

lsusb result:

```
~$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0bc2:ab24 Seagate RSS LLC 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0e0f:0002 VMware, Inc. Virtual USB Hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0e0f:0002 VMware, Inc. Virtual USB Hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0e0f:0003 VMware, Inc. Virtual Mouse
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0e0f:0002 VMware, Inc. Virtual USB Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

sudo fdisk -l result:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 200 GiB, 214748364800 bytes, 419430400 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x8181a6d5

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type

/dev/sda1  *         2048 385878015 385875968  184G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       385880062 419428351  33548290   16G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       385880064 419428351  33548288   16G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

dmesg | tail result:

```
[   52.431393] usb 4-1: stat urb: status -32
[   52.431418] scsi 33:0:0:0: tag#0 data cmplt err -32 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD 
[   52.431420] scsi 33:0:0:0: tag#0 CDB: Inquiry 12 00 00 00 24 00
[   73.964896] scsi 33:0:0:0: tag#0 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD 
[   73.964905] scsi 33:0:0:0: tag#0 CDB: Inquiry 12 00 00 00 24 00
[   73.965084] scsi host33: uas_eh_bus_reset_handler start
[   74.088200] usb 4-1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[   74.111388] usb 4-1: device firmware changed
[   74.140001] scsi host33: uas_post_reset: alloc streams error -19 after reset
[   74.140022] usb 4-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
```

It seems to have allocation error, but I don't know how to fix this.

However, it is working fine on another VM/computer.

Thank you for your help.

xp

Answer (score 2):

After hours searching, this method works for my case:

go to /var/log/syslog to find idVendor and idProduct:

```
 [ 1582.945936] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=ab24
```

turn off uas:

```
echo options usb-storage quirks=0bc2:ab24:u > /etc/modprobe.d/ignore_uas.conf
```

Do this (I don't understand why it needs this though):

```
locale-gen --purge --no-archive
```

unplug the external hard drive and reboot VM

reference source: https://forum.parallels.com/threads/usb-hdd-not-responding.330268/

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issues but later I came up with better solution. Solution is:
open terminal and type below command & you are done,even you don't required to restart.

```
sudo apt install exfat-fuse exfat-utils
```

And provide *sudo* password.

After successful installation open Seagate external/peripheral device

Answer (score 0):

The solution of answer 1 above also worked for me for a "Seagate RSS Fast SSD", but I had to disable the device explicitly in the device manager of the Windows host. After doing this, Ubuntu 18.04 mounted the device in the virtual machine.

Further investigation showed that it is sufficient to use "remove external device" in Windows (instead of disabling the device in device manager), unplug the USB cable and reinsert it. After this, VMware pops up a panel asking if the device should be connected to the VM or the host.

It is possible to use the device on both machines?