# Unable to detect Seagate 2 TB HDD on Dell Vostro 3480

Tags: 18.04, mount, hard-drive, exfat

After constantly facing issues with Windows 10 updates, I decided to switch over to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS as I am somewhat familiar with Ubuntu. However, after successful installation of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, I am facing an issue regarding the detection of Seagate external HDD in Ubuntu.

After searching every forum and having tried everything they proposed (in particular this thread: [Seagate 2T external hard drive can not be mounted, detected by lsusb but not by fdisk -l](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029544/seagate-2t-external-hard-drive-can-not-be-mounted-detected-by-lsusb-but-not-by)), I am still unable to get my HDD detected.

My terminal output of the commands given in the above mentioned thread are as below:

```
# lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bc2:ac2d Seagate RSS LLC 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:5520 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 27c6:5301  
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0cf3:e009 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

```
# sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/loop0: 2.5 MiB, 2621440 bytes, 5120 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop1: 219 MiB, 229638144 bytes, 448512 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop2: 704 KiB, 720896 bytes, 1408 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop3: 4 KiB, 4096 bytes, 8 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop4: 55.4 MiB, 58130432 bytes, 113536 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop5: 295.7 MiB, 310079488 bytes, 605624 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop6: 2.5 MiB, 2605056 bytes, 5088 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop7: 65.2 MiB, 68378624 bytes, 133552 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 1DEA151D-2317-4862-809C-F2F528BD0614

Device       Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048    1050623    1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sda2  1050624    2549759    1499136   732M Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  2549760 1953523711 1950973952 930.3G Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: 929.3 GiB, 997871058944 bytes, 1948966912 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: 976 MiB, 1023410176 bytes, 1998848 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/loop8: 32.3 MiB, 33878016 bytes, 66168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop9: 242.4 MiB, 254115840 bytes, 496320 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop10: 61.8 MiB, 64770048 bytes, 126504 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop11: 548 KiB, 561152 bytes, 1096 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop12: 248.6 MiB, 260681728 bytes, 509144 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

```
# dmesg | tail
[ 4457.505360] CPU1: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 2817)
[ 4457.505361] CPU3: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 2817)
[ 4457.506443] CPU6: Package temperature/speed normal
[ 4457.506443] CPU0: Package temperature/speed normal
[ 4457.506444] CPU2: Package temperature/speed normal
[ 4457.506445] CPU4: Package temperature/speed normal
[ 4457.506485] CPU1: Package temperature/speed normal
[ 4457.506485] CPU5: Package temperature/speed normal
[ 4457.506486] CPU7: Package temperature/speed normal
[ 4457.506487] CPU3: Package temperature/speed normal
```

```
# sudo apt install exfat-fuse exfat-utils
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
exfat-fuse is already the newest version (1.2.8-1).
exfat-utils is already the newest version (1.2.8-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Here is a screenshot of my Files window:

[image: Screenshot of Files window]

I am unable to see my HDD. Please help.

Comment: is your hard drive under "Other Locations"?

Comment: If drive was NTFS, did you leave Windows fast start up on? That sets hibernation flag and prevents other installs from mounting it normally as read/write. Cannot write into hibernated system without causing potential damage. https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation If you do not have Windows, do not use NTFS as it will need chkdsk or defrag which you can only run from Windows. You may be able to manually mount read only.

Comment: @Irsu85 Nope it is not showing under other locations

Answer (score 1):

Thank you guys for helping. I found how it is done.

I visited [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1277208/1463888) to [Ubuntu 18.04 does not mount 2TB exFat drive even after installing exfat-fuse exfat-utils](https://askubuntu.com/q/1057423/348964) and found that for Ubuntu 18.04 following commands are useful:

```
sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils
sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils --fix-missing
```

Now my HDD is showing in the list as Windows.